# Как можно округлить до 0.5 и 1? То есть, если числа 0,1; 0,2; 0,3; 0,4; 0,5; 0,6 - то после округления 0,5. Соответственно 0,7; 0,8; 0,9 - это 1

Tags: angular

//Какие проверки можно сделать, чтобы например использовать Math.ceil(), но так, чтоб округлять до 0.5 и до 1.0. Как пример 10254,34 - 10254,5; 457,12 - 457,5 и 78,7 - 79,0

Comment: умножить на 2, округлить, разделить на два?

Comment: непонятно. почему 0.1 округляется вверх, а не вниз? что должно получиться из 2.1?

Comment: из 2.1 получаем 2.5

Comment: умножить на 2, округлить, разделить на два? По моим расчетам пример выше 457,12 - 457,5 не сработает.

Comment: присмотрелся, какое то странное округление хочется. почему 0.6 округлять до 0.5... если до 1...

Comment: Прибавить 0.3 и отбросить дробную часть. Делов-то.. да или Math.ceil(i * 2) / 2; как был совет в первом комментарии только с поправкой округления в большую сторону